# why can't i assign fruits.sort() to sorted variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**This is my code:**

```
fruits = ["Banana","Cherry","Apple"]
        sorted = fruits.sort()
        print(sorted)
```

so, i have created a list called fruits, and added three strings namely banana, cherry, apple.
I have assigned `fruits.sorted()` to `sorted` variable. Then for the output, `print(sorted)`

when i run the code, i get `none`.
why am i not getting it as `["Apple,"Banana,"Cherry"]`?

Comment: `sort()` doesn't return anything at all, which is how it tells you that it's changing `fruits` _in-place_. `sorted()`, by contrast, returns a new, sorted copy; but `sort()` is different.

Comment: fruits = ["Banana","Cherry","Apple"]
print(sorted(fruits))
This is how you should write it.

Comment: Hint: notice how when you type the code in on Stack Overflow, `sorted` gets syntax highlighting? What happens if you try looking for something named `sorted` in the Python documentation?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't think the fact that `sorted` is a built-in function has anything to do with this question.

Comment: The point is that `sorted` *exists*. Thus that inspires *checking what it does*, and noticing how it is described in the documentation, differently from the `sort` method.